# Oracle INSERT ALL with from select result

Tags: php, sql, oracle

Ok this has been seriously hurting my brain for the last few hours. Can you not use INSERT ALL with SELECT in Oracle?

Here's what I got and it tells me sql command not properly ended

```
   INSERT ALL 
            INTO ENVIRONMENT (NAME, ID, DESCRIPTION, START_DATE, END_DATE) VALUES(:name, :eId, :description, :sDate, :eDate)
            INTO ENVIRONMENT#URL (ID, ENVIRONMENT_ID, URL, URL_TYPE_ID) SELECT 600, :eId, :url, URL_TYPE.ID FROM URL_TYPE WHERE URL_TYPE.TYPE like :urlType
            INTO ENVIRONMENT#CONTACT (ID, ENVIRONMENT_ID, CONTACT_ID) SELECT 600, :eId, CONTACT.ID FROM CONTACT WHERE CONTACT.NAME like :contactName
    SELECT * FROM DUAL
```

This is run using php so thats why there's no semicolon. This works if it's run as 3 different insert statements but it needs to be one query. How else might I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to remove the `INSERT` keywords after the `INSERT ALL` part, like this:

```
INSERT ALL 
            INTO ENVIRONMENT (NAME, ID, DESCRIPTION, START_DATE, END_DATE) VALUES(:name, :eId, :description, :sDate, :eDate)
            INTO ENVIRONMENT#URL (ID, ENVIRONMENT_ID, URL, URL_TYPE_ID) SELECT 600, :eId, :url, URL_TYPE.ID FROM URL_TYPE WHERE URL_TYPE.TYPE like :urlType
            INTO ENVIRONMENT#CONTACT (ID, ENVIRONMENT_ID, CONTACT_ID) SELECT 600, :eId, CONTACT.ID FROM CONTACT WHERE CONTACT.NAME like :contactName
SELECT * FROM DUAL
```

**EDIT**

You know, now that I'm looking at this some more, I see that you have other `SELECT` statements for the last 2 `INTO` clauses.  I don't think that the `INSERT ALL` syntax allows that.  I think you have to use `VALUES` for all the clauses.

Personally, instead of using `INSERT ALL`, I would try wrapping 3 normal `INSERT` statements inside an anonymous PL/SQL block like this (not sure how this works from PHP, I am just telling you that from Oracle's perspective, this is one statement and it works fine):

```
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO ENVIRONMENT (NAME, ID, DESCRIPTION, START_DATE, END_DATE) VALUES(:name, :eId, :description, :sDate, :eDate);
  INSERT INTO ENVIRONMENT#URL (ID, ENVIRONMENT_ID, URL, URL_TYPE_ID) (SELECT 600, :eId, :url, URL_TYPE.ID FROM URL_TYPE WHERE URL_TYPE.TYPE like :urlType);
  INSERT INTO ENVIRONMENT#CONTACT (ID, ENVIRONMENT_ID, CONTACT_ID) (SELECT 600, :eId, CONTACT.ID FROM CONTACT WHERE CONTACT.NAME like :contactName);
END;
```

Comment: Oops, that was actually just a typing mistake when I asked the question. I've changed it in the question, the problem still exists

Comment: What's up with the `#` pound signs.  Are your table names really `ENVIRONMENT#URL` and `ENVIRONMENT#CONTACT`?  I've never seen that before, and I would think that it can be a problem.

Comment: That is the name of the table, I know it looks kinda funny but its been working reliably for many other queries